# How do I take my output from a math equation and plot it on a graph using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, plot, graph, charts

I am looking to do a "stress test", using the mathematical equation stress=force/area (for entertainment purposes). It is simple a simple enough equation, but I am looking to plot/graph the output answer on a chart. For instance, 
How many hours do you have in your workload?
*user inputs 10*

How many days until your workload is due?
*user inputs 5*

so the output answer is 2. I want to plot that 2 on a chart from "a little stressed" to "very stressed", or something like that. It should be simple but I cannot figure it out. Here is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/avanhout13/4ayfxL16/66/

```
<body>
Stress Test<br><br>

How many hours do you have in your workload?<input type="number" id="workLoad"/><br/>
How many days until your workload is due?<input type="number" id="daysLeft"/><br/>

<button onClick="calc();"> Test your stress! </button><br/>

<p id="output"></p>

</body>


function calc()
{
    var workLoad = parseInt(document.getElementById("workLoad").value);
    var daysLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("daysLeft").value);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = workLoad / daysLeft;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I have tried looking everywhere for tutorials or some sort of chart dictionary that allows you to do this with a SINGLE number. Also, I'm really just not sure how to implement my output onto the chart itself. I can only find tutorials where you manually enter the data on the developer side - not where the data is calculated from the user side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to collect stress over time, particularly in relation to a deadline. If I'm wrong, please update the question. It's probably a bad question because it's not addressing a specific technical issue, but I'm a beginner here too so not sure about that

I recommend that you step back to get a better picture of what you are trying to do. Saving stuff over time means you need to save the values, with a date as well as a value. There are lots of ways to do that, the simplest would be with localStorage. Having collected your data, you then want to display it as a graph. Lots of ways to do that too - you should be able to Google that

If I was doing this just to play with for myself, I would use a spreadsheet rather than building a web page.